# ZTE N9130: Video recorded, but doesn't show under Camera, Gallery or a Video player, though it can be seen under File manager

Tags: video

My wife's phone is a ZTE N9130 and it has a rather odd problem when recording video. It'll record, but then the video doesn't appear in the camera application for you to review. In fact, no videos do.

- If you go to the gallery application, they aren't there either.
- If you go to the video player, it looks like no video again.
- *But*, if I go into the File Manager and navigate to `SD Card/DCIM/Camera`, then I can see them. You can then tap one and it'll run in the video player.

This is really annoying. It seems like the camera, gallery and video apps are all missing the videos that are on the SD card. Any way to fix this?

Comment: First thing coming to my mind: check the path "upwards" (i.e. start at `/sdcard/DCIM/Camera`, then `/sdcard/DCIM`, then `/sdcard`) and see whether there's a file named `.nomedia`. If so, remove it. But if that's the cause, photos shouldn't show up either. So try one more thing: reboot the device and check if the videos show up in gallery etc. after that. Let us know about the outcome then. Good luck!

Comment: @Izzy: A reboot was the first thing I tried (this phone has had a number of intermittent problems that are fixed by a reboot). I looked for `.nomedia` and don't see it anywhere. And as you say, I would have expected that to block the photos in the same folder which it doesn't appear to do.

Comment: Afraid if a reboot doesn't make them turn up I'm out of ideas; and while I don't expect it to help, maybe you try some of the [MediaScanner](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/mediascanner) triggering apps?

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully I'm not too late.

I had the same problem I had  been looking for my videos for months. After reading what Izzy replies to you, I realized I was searching the right folder but in the wrong area.

Go to your file manager app icon, it should look like a folder. Once you open it, select phone which is to the immediate right of category. Now you should see a list of different folders. Click on camera and scroll all the way to the very bottom passed all the photos, you should begin to see a small purple triangle indicating videos.

I hope that helps you out.